# Why is my local storage data not adding to an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, local-storage

I have a quiz that ends with logging the high score and user initials in local storage.

When the submit button is clicked for the user initials input, it takes you to the high score page, changing the location with window.location.href. The local storage is saving fine, but I'm having trouble pushing the strings to an array in order to create a high score list when the quiz is retaken. This is the function that I'm working with (the local storage was set in the previous page's JS script).  It currently is overwriting instead of adding to the array.  Why is this?

```
var storageArray = [];

function printHighscores() {

  var userInitials = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userInitials"));
  var highScore = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userScore'));
  storageArray.push(userInitials, highScore);
  console.log(storageArray)
```

Thank you.

Comment: Your function initializes the array to a new empty array (`[]`) in its first line of code.

Comment: Ok I changed that part.  It is still not working correctly